# Were 70,000 caucasians killed in South Africa since Apartheid?

Tags: africa

I came across [this March 2014 interview in Vice](http://www.vice.com/read/the-white-man-march-interview) of Kyle Hunt who organised the (diminuitive) White Man March in 2014.

Interviewer Dave Schilling asked:

> You claim that 70,000 white people were killed since Apartheid. In South Africa in 2010, the murder rate reached 18,000 a year, despite the murder rate in the country having decreased by 44 percent since 1995. Seventy thousand total murders since 1995 would be 5 percent of the total murder rate if South Africa averaged 20,000 murders a year in that period. Is it possible that South Africa is just a poor, violent nation where everyone is suffering? The country is a mess, but it sounds like you're saying Black people are specifically the problem.

Hunt's response was:

> Sorry, but I am very busy. Since 1994, more than 70,000 (and counting) White South Africans have been murdered, of which more than 4,000 were commercial farmers. Exact figures are very hard to come by as the South African police fail to report most of the murders that take place. These numbers are thus conservatively estimated.

Wouldn't this mean that they are operating on hearsay?

Comment: It was unclear what the question was in the original version. I edited the title to ask whether the claimed number of people were killed, but does anyone doubt the figure? The interviewer suggested that the number was not disproportionately high, given the murder rate. The interviewee ignored the suggestion. What is your question? (There's also a question of notability. Does anyone listen to/believe this guy?)

Comment: Well the question is if whites are being singled out in murders in South Africa, especially since they make up 86% of farm owners in the nation

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how to tease out a single claim here. (Can anyone else help?) Your comment shows how complex the question is because of the confounding variables. If *farmers* are being targeted, it is a coincidence that they are white. If *white farmers* are being targeted, the total murder count is irrelevant. Perhaps have a look through the [Wikipedia page on the phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_farm_attacks) and find a more specific and notable claim that you doubt?